# How to combine values based on condition of two different keys in key-value map?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, key-value, rdd

I am struggling with basic operations on key value maps in pyspark. Below is problem description:

```
data = {(1, [2, 3, 4]), (2, [a, b, 3]), (3, [x, y]) }
```

I want to get all the values of the keys that are not contained in the current value list. The result should be like this:

```
data = {(1, [a, b, x, y]), (2, [x, y]), (3, []) }
```

Before even filtering the results I was just trying to combine values, with several approaches:

1. Send data to a function and create nested loops to transform the data: failed as I couldn't get my RDDs to iterate properly
2. Iterate through data using map: `data.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1].map(lambda a,b: (x[a] + x[b])))):` failed as the list doesn't have `map` or `flatMap` attributes
3. Using valuemap method: `data.flatMapValues(lambda a, b: (data.lookup(a) + data.lookup(b))).`

Btw, I am completely new to pyspark so my approaches might be naive, but is there a way to make any of these work or is there different approach that I should use?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something like the following:

1) Collect all the values (Assuming they'll fit in memory. If not, I'd have to think more):

```
values = (data.mapValues(lambda x: set(x))
              .values()
              .reduce(lambda x, y: x.union(y))
              .collect())
```

2) (Probably after broadcasting the values) Map over the values to end up with your final lists

```
data.mapValues(lambda x: [y for y in values if y not in x])
```

> Iterate through data using map: data.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1].map(lambda a,b: (x[a] + x[b])))): failed as the list doesn't have map or flatMap attributes

A quick note on this. You want the Python bultin `map`. The syntax is `map(function, sequence)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have tried your method and it seems that set object doesn't have attribute collect: AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'collect'. Is there any other way to print out what we've got in values? Also, second one has similar issues I encountered before: f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
"It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an RDD from an "

Comment: If I do this: values2 = sc.broadcast (values) and after data.mapValues(lambda x: [y for y in values if y not in x]).collect(). I get an error that the broadcast object is not iterable.

Comment: Oops... you can skip the `collect` step--the reduce takes care of it.

Check the documentation, but I think it'd be `values2.value` to access the actual value of the broadcast variable (maybe I shouldn't have called it values...).